# Is it possible to add a "clear all app button" in android stock

Tags: applications, cache

I'm using a moto G (2015) which has android 6 stock. There is no button to clear all apps launched.  By "clear" I mean quit and delete cache. Some skins have such button sometimes represented by a carpet sweeper icon.

I know there is no need to clear opened applications. Android is managed them, will clear them for you if needed, and if you quit an app manually, she will be slower to open.

*But* I don't like to have a list of recently opened apps (in order) available to whom take my phone. Sometimes, the browser (firefox) remember my last search and I don't want that (I use also inbrowser but needed firefox for the sync feature).

**Is it a simple way to add a clear button to android stock?**

Comment: The Xposed module GravityBox has it, though I'm not sure if it clears the apps as hard as you'd like.

Answer (score 0):

Click whichever button you clicked on your OS to display list of opened apps, and there should be a way to clear/close all of them from this screen. For me there's an X on the bottom middle and displays how much memory these apps used up. Clicking that X closes them all.

Comment: The feature heavily depends on whether the skin of the OEM implemented it. As far as I know, since Moto loads the phone with a skin close to AOSP Android, they have no such button, and that's why OP is asking.

Comment: @AndyYan ah, I see. For me on various phones option to clear all was somewhere on that screen. Though not always so obvious. I saw that X, but it was a while till I figured what it does, because I thought it just exits so I always used back button instead ;)

Comment: A really good Launcher by MS called "Arrow launcher" comes with a dedicated icon on screen that also accomplishes this. But that's a whole launcher so probably not what OP wants. IMHO it's better than Nova Launcher which I was using before. Efficient and clean.